# DataAdapter Update command

Tags: c#, database

I'm using a `DataAdapter` and `DataTable` to edit/add data in a *Oracle db* table, using *ODP.NET* provider.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("report");
DataTable dt = new DataTable("report");
adptr = new OracleDataAdapter();
string myCmd = "select * from report";            

OracleCommand _cmd = new OracleCommand(myCmd, myDbConnection);

adptr.SelectCommand = _cmd;
adptr.Fill(dt);
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

After this i alter the data in the data table, by binding it to a grid and editing it and save like this :

```
OracleCommandBuilder _cmdBld = new OracleCommandBuilder(adptr);
adptr.Update(ds, "report");
```

Everything great by now, it works as it's supposed to, every modification gets commited to the *DB*.
But my problem is the following - when i get data from more than one table.
like this :

```
string myCmd = 
    "select r.id, u.username, r.creation_date, r.owner 
     from report r inner join users u on r.user_id == u.id";
```

I know I could write the `DataAdapter`'s update command manually (`DataAdapter.UpdateCommand`) , before saving, but i'm not sure how. Can you give me some directions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the example provided in MSDN. I guess OracleDataAdapter works with same logic.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand.aspx

Here is the update command generation section from specified link

```
// Create the UpdateCommand.
command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Customers SET CustomerID = @CustomerID, "+
     "CompanyName = @CompanyName WHERE CustomerID = @oldCustomerID", connection);
// Add the parameters for the UpdateCommand.
command.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID");
command.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40, "CompanyName");
SqlParameter parameter = command.Parameters.Add("@oldCustomerID", 
     SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID");
parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;    
adapter.UpdateCommand = command;
```

Comment: thanks! but how would the insert or update command look if the data was provided from two joined tables as in my example ?